# MS access query not finding table and field

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have been working with access for many years and writing queries.

Now I am hitting a wall. My query is simple and has 2 tables.

Table No.1 "fraud_IP_Blocks_country" and fields are "IP Block" and "Country"
Table No.2 "web_Cdr_export" Fields are "Originating TG" and "ANI"

My Query is as follows

```
SELECT web_Cdr_export.[Originating TG]
, web_Cdr_export.[Inpulsed Digits]
, web_Cdr_export.ANI
FROM web_Cdr_export
WHERE (((Left([fraud_IP_Blocks_country]![IP Block],1) & ".")
                    =Left([web_Cdr_export]![Originating TG],1) & "."));
```

When I run query I get

> "Enter parameter value" for field "fraud_IP_blocks_country!IP BLOCK

I am having trouble figuring out what could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing "fraud_IP_Blocks_country" reference in your FROM clause.  Please try this:

```
SELECT web_Cdr_export.[Originating TG], web_Cdr_export.[Inpulsed Digits],
web_Cdr_export.ANI 
FROM fraud_IP_Blocks_country, web_Cdr_export 
WHERE 
(((Left([fraud_IP_Blocks_country]![IP Block],1) & ".") = 
Left([web_Cdr_export]![Originating TG],1) & "."));
```

Comment: Kind people please disregard my issue I found the answer after pulling it apart. I for got to add the 2nd table to the query. Very stupid mistake as I said I am getting to OLD

Answer (score 0):

Kind people please disregard my issue I found the answer after pulling it apart. I for got to add the 2nd table to the query. Very stupid mistake as I said I am getting to OLD